# DB Credentials Exposed as part job parameters when executing a task from SCDF

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, spring-batch, openshift, spring-cloud-dataflow

I have Custom Built SCDF which is built as docker image in Openshift and referred in server-deployment.yaml as docker image.I use the Oracle db to store the task meta data and is an external source here. I pass the all db properties in configmap. The DB password is base64 encoded and added in config map as secret. These db details are being used by SCDF to store task metadata.

These job parameters are passed by SCDF to the executing job.But these job parameters which in turn are the datasource properties including the db password present in the configmap are being printed in logs as Job parameters, and batch_job_execution_params table.

I thought using the password as secret in configmap should resolve this. But it's not. Below is the logs and table snippet of job parameters being printed.

**I would like to know how to avoid passing these db properties as job parameters to the executing job so to prevent the credentials being exposed?**

```
12-06-2020 18:12:38.540 [main] INFO org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run - Job: 
[FlowJob: [name=Job]] launched with the following parameters: [{
-spring.cloud.task.executionid=8010, 
-spring.cloud.data.flow.platformname=default, 
-spring.datasource.username=ACTUAL_USERNAME, 
-spring.cloud.task.name=Alljobs, 
Job.ID=1591985558466, 
-spring.datasource.password=ACTUAL_PASSWORD, 
-spring.datasource.driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver, 
-spring.datasource.url=DATASOURCE_URL, 
-spring.batch.job.names=Job_1}]
```

**Pod Created for the Job execution - openshift screenshot**
[image: openshift screenshot]

**Database Table**
[image: Database Table]

```
Custom SCDF Dockerfile.yaml
===========================
FROM maven:3.5.2-jdk-8-alpine AS MAVEN_BUILD

COPY pom.xml /build/
COPY src /build/src/

WORKDIR /build/
RUN mvn package

FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine

WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=MAVEN_BUILD /build/target/BatchAdmin-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /app/

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "BatchAdmin-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]

Deployment.yaml
===============
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: scdf-server
  labels:
    app: scdf-server
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: scdf-server
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: scdf-server
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: scdf-server
        image: docker-registry.default.svc:5000/batchadmin/scdf-server #DockerImage
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        volumeMounts:
          - name: config
            mountPath: /config
            readOnly: true
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /management/health
            port: 80
          initialDelaySeconds: 45
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /management/info
            port: 80
          initialDelaySeconds: 45
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 1.0
            memory: 2048Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 0.5
            memory: 1024Mi
        env:
        - name: KUBERNETES_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: "metadata.namespace"
        - name: SERVER_PORT
          value: '80'
        - name: SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_ENABLED
          value: 'false'
        - name: SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_FEATURES_ANALYTICS_ENABLED
          value: 'true'
        - name: SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_FEATURES_SCHEDULES_ENABLED
          value: 'true'
        - name: SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_TASK_COMPOSED_TASK_RUNNER_URI
          value: 'docker://springcloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-composed-task-runner:2.6.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT'
        - name: SPRING_CLOUD_KUBERNETES_CONFIG_ENABLE_API
          value: 'true'
        - name: SPRING_CLOUD_KUBERNETES_SECRETS_ENABLE_API
          value: 'true'
        - name: SPRING_CLOUD_KUBERNETES_SECRETS_PATHS
          value: /etc/secrets
        - name: SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_FEATURES_TASKS_ENABLED
          value: 'true'
        - name: SPRING_CLOUD_KUBERNETES_CONFIG_NAME
          value: scdf-server
        - name: SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_SERVER_URI
          value: 'http://${SCDF_SERVER_SERVICE_HOST}:${SCDF_SERVER_SERVICE_PORT}'
          # Add Maven repo for metadata artifact resolution for all stream apps
        - name: SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON
          value: "{ \"maven\": { \"local-repository\": null, \"remote-repositories\": { \"repo1\": { \"url\": \"https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot\"} } } }"
      serviceAccountName: scdf-sa
      volumes:
        - name: config
          configMap:
            name: scdf-server
            items:
            - key: application.yaml
              path: application.yaml


#- name: SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_FEATURES_TASKS_ENABLED
#value : 'true'

server-config.yaml
==================
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: scdf-server
  labels:
    app: scdf-server
data:
  application.yaml: |-
    spring:
      cloud:
        dataflow:
          task:
            platform:
              kubernetes:
                accounts:
                  default:
                    limits:
                        memory: 1024Mi
                        cpu: 2
                entry-point-style: exec
                image-pull-policy: always
      datasource:
        url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@db_url
        username: BATCH_APP
        password: ${oracle-root-password}
        driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
        testOnBorrow: true
        validationQuery: "SELECT 1"
      flyway:
        enabled: false
      jpa:
        hibernate:
          use-new-id-generator-mappings: true

oracle-secrets.yaml
===================
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: oracle
  labels:
    app: oracle
data:
  oracle-root-password: a2xldT3ederhgyzFCajE4YQ==
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. Can you clarify what your question is?

Comment: Updated the question with little more information. It's Basically, When the job is executed in kubernetes platform via SCDF, the job parameters being passed by SCDF contains db credentials. How to avoid that?

Comment: This is being tracked here: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/issues/3985

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SCDF V2.6.2 the team fixed this issue. The DB credentials are no longer exposed in logs, POD Description page or Database. By default, the credentials would be visible. So anyone who have this issue have to do is add the following environment variable as part of the Deployment configuration and set the value to true.

`SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_TASK_USE_KUBERNETES_SECRETS_FOR_DB_CREDENTIALS = true`

Comment: Glad they fixed it. My team is still stuck with SCDF 1.7.x...

Answer (score 1):

This is not a perfect example - but you can mask the password in the log by using features of logback (default logging lib used by Spring Boot)

Put the below configuration into your logback, it would replace the password by ****

```
<springProfile name="local">
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/console-appender.xml"/>
    <appender name="console" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>
                %d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36}.%M - %replace(%msg){'password=\S*', 'password=****'}%n
            </pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="console"/>
    </root>
</springProfile>
```

For the password logged in database, look like we are out of luck. The best thing we can do is to put it in a separate schema and have specific permissions to access those SCDF tables.

Comment: Thanks Hoang for the answer. Thankfully the scdf it self has resolved this issue as part of their release. I'll provide those details in a separate answer.

Comment: Thanks @Rajesh2389 for the update :). My team has similar problems and we can't upgrade SCDF yet. I'll keep the answer for now in case anyone have the same problem.